# HTTP to HTTPS Redirect in IIS

Tags: asp.net, ssl, https, url-rewriting, acumatica

I have to redirect my site from http to https, whenever any user open my site using http.

For example: -

http:\\abc.mywebsite.com  should go to https:\\abc.mywebsite.com

Notice that in above URL, it is not www.mywebsite.com, instead it is custom URL as abc.mywebsite.com.

I have tried [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) tool and followed all steps mentioned [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https).  However, I cannot get URL Rewrite to work properly to redirect.

Here is the URL Redirect rule looks like in IIS: -

[image]

Here is how my web.config looks like after adding rule using URL Rewrite.

```html
<configuration>
  .....
  .....
  .....
  <system.webServer>
    .....
    .....
    .....
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Http to Https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
           <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
           </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  .....
  .....
  .....
</configuration>
```

I have also uncheck Require SSL check box under SSL Settings.

However, after doing all this, my website is still not redirecting to https. Just giving error "...can't reach this page".

Please suggest if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

I have some doubts about the rewrite rules because I see many examples that are different.

Trying different values like the one from this [Microsoft Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/) could yield better results:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to http" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" negate="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

You can also setup [Tracing for Failed Requests in IIS 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731798(v=ws.10)). This could give you insight into why it's failing to redirect.

Comment: Thanks HB_Acumatica, I will sure try the tracing. Regarding Microsoft Blog, I have tried that and many other options/suggestions for the same, but nothing worked.

Comment: Microsoft Blog link has a full step by step tutorial on HTTP->HTTPS, personally I would try to follow it as closely as possible and after that debug with the tracing logs. Information there is likely more reliable than elsewhere since it came from a MS employee.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue within the same site when trying to redirect from http to https. 
I did created new site and added the binding as http://www.example.com/
And then I have created new Http Redirect and added my https://www.example.com/ it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have setup the bindings correctly in IIS, the second line highlighted in red should be there.

1. Type = HTTPS
2. Host Name = the site address like "site.domain.com"
3. Port = 443
4. IP Address = The IP Address of the server you are trying to access.

[image: IIS Binding]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how my URL rewrite looks:

Note that it's applied at the site level

[image: url rewrite]